# django-rest save array of data to db

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

hi im trying to save a form data into db.
 i provided print of `requset.data` for you as you see `requirement` have two items.

i want to save each item in database i used for loop to save each item of list but the loop will save each character of item like `h-e-l,...` in table row...
where is my mistake ... thanks

also print of `request.data.get('requirement')` will retun second item

this is print of request.data in sever:

```
<QueryDict: {'requirement': ['hello', 'bye'], 'audience': ['adasd'], 'achievement': ['asdasd'], 'section': ['410101010'], 'title': ['asdasd'], 'mini_description': ['asdad'], 'full_description': ['asdasd'], 'video_length': ['10101'], 'video_level': ['P'], 'price': [''], 'free': ['true'], 'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: p.gif (image/gif)>]}>
```

view:

```
class StoreCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.data)
            file_serial = ProductSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            if file_serial.is_valid():
                file_serial.save(author_id=request.user.id)
                requirement = request.data['requirement']
                audience = request.data.get('audience')
                achievement = request.data.get('achievement')
                sections = request.data.get('section')

                print(request.data['requirement'])
                pid = file_serial.data.get('product_id')
                for item in requirement :
                    req = ProductRequiredItems(
                        item = item,
                        product_id = pid
                    )
                    req.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, overriding `CreateAPIView`'s `post` method in your code makes your custom `perform_create` method useless, unless you explicitly call it from within your customized `post` method. Otherwise it will never be called.

> also print of request.data.get('requirement') will retun second item

It does return the last item as per Django docs for [`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__).

> i want to save each item in database i used for loop to save each item of list but the loop will save each character of item like h-e-l,...

This is because of the above functionality of `QueryDict`. When you do:

```
requirement = request.data['requirement']
# requirement = request.__getitem__('requirement')
```

it will call `QueryDict.__getitem__(key)` method and thus return only the last item (which is string in you example).

**Answer:**

You can simply override `CreateAPIView`'s `create` method, and let your serializer handle all the rest.

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import MyObj
from .serializers import MyObjSerializer

class MyObjView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyObjSerializer
    queryset = MyObj.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # The QueryDicts at request.POST and request.GET will be immutable 
        # when accessed in a normal request/response cycle. 
        # To get a mutable version you need to use QueryDict.copy().
        req_data = request.data.copy()
        requirements = req_data.pop('requirement')
        serializers_data = []
        for requirement in requirements:
            req_data ['requirement'] = requirement
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=req_data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            serializers_data.append(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializers_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import MyObj

class MyObjSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyObj
        fields = '__all__'
```

Have a look at DRF [`CreateModelMixin`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L14). It defines `create` & `perform_create` methods that are used used in [`CreateAPIView`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L186) upon executing POST request. I just altered them slightly to handle your specific case.

Hope it helps.